# Error message trying to commit a .gitignore

Tags: git, vim

I'm a beginner with git and am getting an initial project set up and have just created a .gitignore file and am trying to push it but getting an error on commit.

I've created a remote repository and cloned it and done a few test commits/pushes/pulls.

Now I've just created a .gitignore and want to push it to the remote repository. If I do "git status" I get:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .gitignore
```

But if I try to do "git commit .gitignore" I get this:

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp"
          owned by: Me   dated: Mon Mar 25 15:51:27 2013
         file name: ~Me/Desktop/MyProject/iOS/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
          modified: YES
         user name: Me   host name: Me-MacBook-Pro.local
        process ID: 28500
While opening file ".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG"
             dated: Mon Mar 25 16:32:44 2013
      NEWER than swap file!
```

Why is this and how should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is actually coming from vim. It's not a git message at all. It's telling you that vim crashed (or was killed) while it was editing a git commit message about 45 minutes ago.

Vim should have asked you how you wanted to proceed. You should just tell it to ignore the swap file.

Comment: First try `vi -r .git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG`, just in case it has content you might want to save.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It's a git commit message that's 45 minutes old.

Comment: Thanks, how do I tell it to ignore the swap file? I've done the vi -r but I still get the message on commit. How can I get vi to shut up?

Comment: @Mungbeans: In gvim it asks me. I haven't actually run into this case in terminal vim, but I'm surprised it's not prompting you. In any case, you can just `rm .git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp` if you want.

Comment: Does it mean that vim crashed, or that it's still running? Try `ps -f -p $$`. If the process is running, and you can find the window, quit the editor; if you can't find it, kill the process. Then delete the `.swp` file.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Actually that's a good point, he could have a still-running Vim instance lying around, instead of it having crashed.

Comment: @KeithThompson `process ID: 28500` in message means that vim is running. You also don’t need to search for vim, this PID can be used to kill it right away.

Comment: @ZyX: Yes, but I prefer to find the window and exit cleanly rather than killing the process.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps try to remove the file from the repo then commit the ignore

```
git rm --cached filename
```